# Apps Script Copy and Paste Rows if Condition is Met In Few Pages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Now, I’m using Apps Script in Google Sheet.
I’ve a few pages with respective details for each quotation number.
How to Copy and Paste specific rows from specific sheets to its same sheet at the bottom(after last row) when condition is met.

Let say, I need all details for GE-2108-0271-Rev.0 quotation number in few pages to be copy and paste at the same sheet itself.
And the quotation number increment by 1 . So it would be GE-2108-0271-Rev.1 after paste it.
To be exact, here is an example:

Page 1:
to be exact I need the number increment by 1 from GE-2108-0271-Rev.0 to GE-2108-0271-Rev.1 (column 2)
[image]

Page 2:
let say got 3 items

[image]

Page 3:
Let say got 1 item
[image]

Here, I try to make it happen for one sheet : M-Items
This is where i stuck

```
    function CopyRange() {
    var sourcespread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('2032798963'); //replace with source ID
      var sourcesheet = sourcespread.getSheetByName('M-Front'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
      var destspread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('977978664'); //replace with destination ID
      var destsheet = destspread.getSheetByName('M-Items'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
      var testrange = sourcesheet.getRange('M:M');
      var testvalue = (testrange.setNumberFormat("0").getValues());
      var data = [];
      var j =[];
    
      for (i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
        if (testvalue[i] /= 0) {
        data.push.apply(data,sourcesheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,3).getValues());
      //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
        j.push(i);
    }  
    }
      //Copy data array to destination sheet
      destsheet.getRange(destsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Rubén

 It something looks like this: 

Step 1 : Triggered the new row, Check whether the Column M:M is not Zero. If else, stop. For your information the column M;M is the revision number at the back. If quotation number GE-2108-0271-Rev.0. column M:M is zero. if GE-2108-0271-Rev.1,     the column M:M is 1. 

Step 2 : At M-Front, check column A:A 

Step 3 : At M-Items, check row which its Column A:A = [column A:A (M-Front)] AND [column M:M (M-Front)] = [column C:C (M-Items)-1] 

Step 4 :

Comment: @lamblichus Step 4 : Select Step 3 which is TRUE, copy and paste at the same sheet (M-Items) to the bottom AND column C increment by 1 and quotation number increment as well.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, free of sensitive information?

Comment: Why `testvalue[i] /= 0` is used? Do you know what `/=` does? P.S. The [best practices docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) discourages using methods like `getRange` in loops.